# If $P(A) = 0$, then can we conclude that $Q(A) = 0 $ ??

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $( \Omega, \mathscr{A}, P ) $ is probability space. $X$ is r.v. such that $X \geq 0 $ almost surely and $\mathbb{E} \{ X \}  = 1 $. Suppose $\exists A \in \mathscr{A}$ s.t. $P(A) = 0$, is it true that $Q(A) = 0 $ as well??

$Q(A) = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb P} \{ X 1_A \} $

Comment: What is $Q$? Thanks.

Comment: updated.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P(A)=0$, then $X\mathbf{1}_A=0$ almost surely with respect to $P$. Thus $Q(A)=\mathbb{E}_P[X\mathbf{1}_A]=0$.

Comment: Why does $X 1_A = 0 $ a.s ?

Comment: Because $\mathbf{1}_A=0$ almost surely (with respect to $P$).

Comment: Thank you very much! But $X 1_A = 0 $ almost surely implies $Q(A) = 0 $ almost surely. I want this to hold everywhere.

Comment: No it doesn't. $Q(A)$ is not random, it's a real number.

Comment: Stefan, why do you say with respect to P? Is it just for emphasis or is Q a probability measure as well? (I was expecting an R-N derivative somewhere) Also, real numbers are random variables :P

Comment: Yes, real numbers are random variables and of course $Q(A)=0$ also holds almost surely (with respect to any probability measure) since it actually holds _everywhere_, but I doubt this is what the OP meant. The point I was trying to make was that constants are either equal to 0 (everywhere) or not and hence the statement "$Q(A)=0$ almost surely" suggests that the OP has misunderstood something. I say with respect to $P$ to emphasize which probability measure the statement "almost surely" holds for. Yes, $Q$ is a probability since it's assumed that $\mathbb{E}_P[X]=1$

Comment: @StefanHansen There's still the matter of how countable additivity but anyway that looks easy to prove. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack: Yes, that's an easy consequence of the monotone convergence theorem.